# Is it possible to have separate initramfs images with different versions of the same DKMS module?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, nvidia, kernel-modules, initramfs

I'm wanting to have a setup where I can essentially have two versions of the NVIDIA driver kernel module installed at the same time. I want to go about this by having two initramfs images to boot from via GRUB; one with an old LTS kernel containing an older patched version of the NVIDIA driver (for special workloads), and one containing the latest kernel and driver (for general use). Is this possible to do, and if so, how could I go about doing this?

I'm running EndeavourOS (an arch-based distro), so I have tools like mkinitcpio at my disposal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An initramfs image is usually specific to a particular kernel version, as it only contains kernel modules for that kernel.

So assuming that your distribution will automatically present all installed kernels in GRUB boot menu (most distributions do that by default), just install your kernels and the drivers for them.

If you use `dkms` to manage your third-party modules (even NVIDIA's binary installer has the `--dkms` option), you might want to add some custom configuration files to `/etc/dkms/` to restrict particular versions of the NVIDIA driver modules to particular kernel versions: it is not strictly necessary, but would probably help in keeping `dkms` from trying to auto-rebuild the old version of the driver anytime you update the latest kernel.

Depending on exactly how your distribution builds the default GRUB menu for you, you might be able to use the standard menu as-is, or might want to create a custom entry for the special workloads kernel (+ its initramfs) to make it more obvious.

What you might have a problem with is the NVIDIA OpenGL libraries. The patched driver package would tend to bring in/depend on an older version of those libraries, while the latest driver would bring a newer set of libraries.